# Spring Boot - add external property files

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, configuration-files

I have simple MVC application in SpringBoot, created using java-config (I don't have web.xml).
That application have DB connection based on JPA. Until now, all was great, but now I must move db.properties from inside of WAR to location specified by OS variable ("CONFIG_LOCATION").
In [spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) is written about that not too much. There is only say that it is posible, but how I should set that in my Spring application?
I suppose that should be done before initializer.
Then I see only two options:
- SpringApplication - there is somewhere a place where I should insert files location from OS variable but I can't find it,
- some annotation, that will understond OS variable, and add files from it to spring context before EntityManager will be created.

I'm open to suggestion how should I do that.

Comment: Cannot agree more to the following: the "spring doc written about that is not much"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way.

I created class what return PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.
In that PSPC i get OS variable, and scan all files in that location.
After scan I was add all files with properties extension to PSCS as locations.
Method is @Bean, and class is @Configuration. After that all works fine :)

```java
imports...

@Configuration
public class AppServiceLoader {
    @Bean(name = "propLoader")
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

        String mainConfigPath = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(System.getenv("CONFIG_LOCATION"))
                ? System.getenv("CONFIG_LOCATION") : System.getProperties().getProperty("CONFIG_LOCATION");

        File configFolder = new File(mainConfigPath);

        if(configFolder.isDirectory()) {
            FilenameFilter ff = new FilenameFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File file, String string) {
                    return string.endsWith(".properties");
                }
            };
            File[] listFiles = configFolder.listFiles(ff);
            Resource[] resources = new Resource[listFiles.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {
                if(listFiles[i].isFile()) {
                    resources[i] = new FileSystemResource(listFiles[i]);
                }
            }
            pspc.setLocations(resources);
        }

        pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return pspc;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in another answer [@PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) annotation is the way to go (I'll add some details). In Java 8 you can apply it several times to your configuration class, and the order matters! For example you can make this configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:/db.properties")
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "file:${MY_APP_HOME}/db.properties")
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "file:${user.home}/.myapp/db.properties")
@ComponentScan("com.myorg")
public class Application {
     // ....
}
```

Here I assume that you should have `MY_APP_HOME` environment variable, and also you might want to place some settings in user home. But both configs are optional because of `ignoreResourceNotFound` set to true.

Also note on the order. You may have some reasonable settings for development environment in `src/main/resources/db.properties`. And put specific settings in host OS where your production service runs.

Look at the `Resolving ${...} placeholders within @PropertySource resource locations` section in [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the config parameters of spring-boot, it is just to specify the config location on execute jar or war, with parameter --spring.config.location.

Example:

`$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=/opt/webapps/db.properties`

Comment: alternatively to command line argument, you can use SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION system variable as well

Comment: Ok, that should work, but what if I have more (10+) property files in some location?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want Spring to reference an external properties file under your project root.
Here is a simpler solution:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${user.dir}/your_external_file.properties")
public class TestConfig {
  @Autowired
  Environment env;
}
```

You can change the ${user.dir} to ${user.home} if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the annotation `@PropertySource`. It's more clear and clean than the code solution.

See: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

For instance:

`@Configuration
     @PropertySource("classpath:/com/myco/app.properties")
     public class AppConfig {
         ...`

Comment: I prefer annotation way, but plz tell me how to do it with OS variable?
And for all files in folder, not only for listed in annotation?

Comment: You can define some classes with @PropertySource and @Profile("xxxx"), so only those that match the current profile load its property file. Then you can choose the current profile with an OS variable: -Dspring.profiles.active